# Search all tables in database and return a value?

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and working off of the follow example [HERE](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2).

Below is the code I have so far. (The only difference is a turned it into a query from a stored procedure and removed schema name which wasn't necessary.)

What I'd like to do is add another column to the result and give the first column's data value. In other words if each table starts off with a Primary Key, my result will include the Primary Key of the row where the data was found. Is this even possible? Thanks.

```
DECLARE @DataToFind nvarchar(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @ExactMatch BIT = 0

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

    INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
    SELECT  C.Table_Name,C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.Column_Name, C.Data_Type
    FROM    Information_Schema.Columns AS C
            INNER Join Information_Schema.Tables AS T
                ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE   Table_Type = 'Base Table'
            And Data_Type In ('ntext','text','nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char')


DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DataExists BIT
DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @ExactMatch = 1
                            THEN 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       = ''' + @DataToFind + '''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            ELSE 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       Like ''%' + @DataToFind + '%''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            END,
        @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
        @i = 1

SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
FROM   @Temp

WHILE @i <= @MAX
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
        FROM    @Temp
        WHERE   RowId = @i


        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

        IF @DataExists =1
            UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT  TableName, ColumnName
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   DataFound = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning the primary key is absolutely possible. You will need to:

- Determine the name if the primary key column or columns in each table. If you can stick to a single column, it will make your life much easier.
- Add a variable for the content of the Primary Key value, say `@PrimaryKeyValue`
- Modify `@SQLTemplate` to return the value of this column into `@PrimaryKeyValue`, something like this:

  ```
  SELECT @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @ExactMatch = 1
                             THEN 'select @PrimaryKeyValue = min(' + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + ')
                                      from ReplaceTableName
                                     where Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName]) = ''' + @DataToFind + ''')'
                             ELSE 'select @PrimaryKeyValue = min(' + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + ')
                                      from ReplaceTableName
                                     where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName]) Like ''%' + @DataToFind + '%'')'
                        END,
         @PARAMETERS = '@PrimaryKeyValue nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT',
         @i = 1
  ```